# Magento 2 - Version 2.2 - Override Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail

Tags: overriding, sendmail, magento2

**Hallo everyone,**

since the release of Magento 2.2 the old override Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail does not work anymore.

before, an rewrite in etc/di.xml and model/Transport.php worked.

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport" type="MyModul\MyPlugin\Model\Transport"/>
```

and

```
namespace MyModul\MyPlugin\Model;

class Transport extends \Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail implements \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface
{

    protected $_message;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface $message
     * @throws \Zend_Mail_Exception
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface $message
    )
    {
        if (!$message instanceof \Zend_Mail) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The message should be an instance of \Zend_Mail');
        }

        parent::__construct('-f ' . 'test@test.de');
        $this->_message = $message;
    }



   /**
     * Send a mail using this transport
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
     */
    public function sendMessage()
    {
        try {
            parent::send($this->_message);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->_message;
    }

    /**
     * Send mail using PHP native mail()
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     * @throws Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception if parameters is set
     *         but not a string
     * @throws Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception on mail() failure
     */
    public function _sendMail()
    {

        /**
         *  revert changes from update to 2.1.7
         *
         *  mailing was not working with Envelope >= 2.1.7
         */
        if ($this->parameters === null) {
            set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
            $result = mail(
                $this->recipients,
                $this->_mail->getSubject(),
                $this->body,
                $this->header);
            restore_error_handler();
        } else {
            if(!is_string($this->parameters)) {
                /**
                 * @see Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception
                 *
                 * Exception is thrown here because
                 * $parameters is a public property
                 */
                #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Exception.php';
                throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception(
                    'Parameters were set but are not a string'
                );
            }

            set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
            $result = mail(
                $this->recipients,
                $this->_mail->getSubject(),
                $this->body,
                $this->header,
                $this->parameters);
            restore_error_handler();
        }

        if ($this->_errstr !== null || !$result) {
            /**
             * @see Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception
             */
            #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception('Unable to send mail. ' . $this->_errstr);
        }
    }
}
```

**But now i am kind of lost**

I tryed creating a plugin, which seem to be the ways it is supposed to be done now.

```
<type name="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport">
    <plugin sortOrder="50" name="SendMailPlugin" type="MyModul\MyPlugin\Plugin\SendMailPlugin"/>
</type>
```

I also read about overriding "TransportInterface", but i am not getting it to work. I only need it to call the constructor on my plugin.

best regards and thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

It is working again now. The Problem was really just the TransportInterface. I thought i tryed that already or maybe it had something to do with "generation" cache ...

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface" type="MyModul\MyPlugin\Model\Transport" />
```

So when override a class the preference needs to point to the interface.

I did not get the plugin version to work yet. In my first attempts i was not even sure how to call the methode in the plugin "after__construct" or "afterConstruct". Also it is calling the parent::contruct.

If i get it to work in the end i will post it.

Thanks you all for your help.

**UPDATE 2:**

A Plugin solution ist not possible in this case, since contruct methodes can not be set for a plugin.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

Comment: You should give this a go on magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all you misunderstand the role of plugins in Magento 2. You try to use it as a class which overrides another class but this is a wrong approach. With plugins you are able to wrap public methods in a class either by changing input, output or both. You can read more about plugins in [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

What you are looking for is an override in M2 fashion so you need to get familiar with dependency injection and [preferences](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html)

Your initial approach is correct. Do you have properly configured sequence in your module to make sure that your module is loaded after Magento_Email? Verify the sequence in etc/config.php

Another thing you can try is to set preference for TransportInterface rather than on transport model especially if your override is global.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use plugin for model
app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Transport.php

Create yours `di.xml` in the folder of your module

```
<config>
<type name="Magento\Email\Model\Transport">
  <plugin name="yourpluginforemail" type="\My\Module\Model\MyPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

And your plugin file should be looke like

```
    <?php

namespace My\Module\Model;

class MyPlugin
{
    public function afterSendEmail($subject, $result)
    {
        return 'some thing else'
    }
}
?>
```

Or if you want, you can override this file by creation own and set sequence

die.xml in your module

and

module.xml

```
<module name="My_Module" setup_version="2.0.1">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Email"/>

            </sequence>
        </module>
```

Then it will override it.

So two ways - override class or one method via "after", "before" "around" plugin

Answer (score 0):

> Bartosz Herba

solution worked in single shot. Thank you.